# Как блокировать IP если он посылает много запросов?

Tags: apache, защита

У меня есть блог. Бывает несколько раз в неделю какой ни будь IP посылает запросов 20-30 и сайт падает на несколько минут. Как правило это запрос к несуществующей странице и вызов ошибки 404. Не катастрофично, но все равно не приятно. Хочется как то решить это.

Возможно вопрос не новый, но конкретного ответа я так и не нашел. С помощью чего можно организовать небольшую защиту на сайте, чтобы автоматически блокировались IP на сутки например, если они посылают более чем 10-20 запросов в секунду?

Может есть какие PHP скрипты, или приложения для Linux для Apache? Claudflare не предлагать. Серьёзные ДДос атаки мне отражать не нужно.

PS
Читал про file2ban, но если я правильно понял, он дает защиту только от множественных попыток авторизаций через форму.

Comment: Если у вас сайт падает от совершенно жалких 20-30 запросов, то вам нужно не защиты ставить, а сайт оптимизировать

Comment: Сайт в общем работает стабильно. Он оптимизирован. Обычные запросы по боку. Движок Joomla. Проблема именно со страницей 404. Почему то она создает большую нагрузку. С чем связано не понятно. Именно к ней обращения активные вешают сайт.

Comment: Если ошибка 404 создаёт нагрузку, это явно говорит о том, что с оптимизацией сайта всё очень плохо

Comment: При обычном серфинге никакой нагрузки нет. Это скорее всего что-то от движка. Уже не на первом проекте замечаю как страница 404 при множественных запросах валит сайт. Я займусь этим вопросом, попробую разобраться что там не так. Но хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос, поставленный в посте.

Comment: 1. Про f2b ты не правильно понял - формы не причём. Он как раз для подобных блокировок (но и не только). 2 Главное! У тебя [проблема молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710). Нужно прежде всего с сайтом и сервером работать - 20-30 запросов это ничто.

Comment: Вопрос с 404 и нагрузкой решил. Переделал ее правильно и больше она не создает нагрузку. Про f2b значит почитаю подробнее.